# Using assets in robolectric tests

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing

In my robolectric tests I am trying to read a file.
Since this file contains just the test data I have put it in assets of the tests.

The directory structure looks like this.
`src/main/assets/prod_data_file`
`src/test/assets/test_data_file`

However when I try to read the file by `getShadowApplication().getAssets().open(MY_FILE_PATH)` it gives me `FileNotFoundException`.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: You have to put your file in the assets folder. After that use the file name for `InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open(filename);`.

Comment: assets in the tests directory? or assets in the app directory?

Comment: Hmmm? Sorry i know of no test directory in an Eclipse environment. I'm not aware of an app directory either. Ment was the assets directory of the project.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since my tests are just reading these files and returning file data as a `String` I was able to do that via `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(MY_FILE_PATH)` and then read file. Dont really need to read to use `getShadowApplication().getAssets().open(MY_FILE_PATH)`.

I just moved my test data files to `src/test/resources` and it worked. :)

Comment: The reason, why you got this error is that the test tasks (not the androidTest) are used fro unit tests, and no assets at all are copied for these tasks (as of May 2015). So even though AS nicely highlights the asset folder in `src/test` it has no relevance at all. No APK is build, so usually you should not be able to access assets, only that robolectric gives you now the possibility to do so.

Comment: Thanks it saved me a day

Comment: Great, thanks! This way files are being excluded from release apk or aar file.

Comment: not to mix up res directory with resources directory!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it like this:

1) Copy (or create) AndroidManifest.xml in test folder

2) Add `@Config(emulateSdk = 18, manifest = "src/test/AndroidManifest.xml")` for this specific test

I was able to read file. So it means you could play with `AndroidManifest` class and custom runner (more inspiration here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robolectric/YvbdqRFcdnA)

I think it could be also possible to play with `build.gradle`:

```
android {
  sourceSets {
    androidTest.setRoot( 'src/test' )

    androidTest {
      assets.srcDir file( 'src/test/assets' )
    }
  }
}
```

but I'm not sure since plugin doesn't create any build variant but just tasks.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, create test assets folder (right click on the test directory -> New -> Directory -> pick assets from the list).
Add your file in the test assets folder you just created.
In your Robolectric test you can read the file like this:

```
val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
context.resources.assets.open(SOME_FILENAME)
    .bufferedReader()
```